# Don't dismiss AlertDialog if EditText is empty

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-alertdialog

Despite a lot of searches and trials, I can't avoid my AlertDialog to close if my EditText is empty... I saw that it was a current issue on StackOverflow with a lot of responses but when I try it, it doesn't work...

Here is my Kotlin code, thanks for your help...

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface

private fun showMyEditextDialog() {
    val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null)
    val myedittext = view.findViewById(R.id.myedittext) as EditText


    alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.title))
    alertDialog.setView(view)
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface, i ->
        var isValid = true

        if ( isEmpty(myedittext.text.toString()) ) {
            isValid = false
            Toast.makeText(this, "empty", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show()
        }

        if ( isValid ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "yeah!", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show()        }

        if ( isValid ) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
        }

    })
}
```

My xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/question" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myedittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

If I enter a value, I've got my "*yeah*" message.
If I don't enter a value, I've got my "*empty*" message but my dialog dismiss...

Thanks for your help,

MT

Comment: This works as designed. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs: "When the user touches any of the action buttons created with an AlertDialog.Builder, the system dismisses the dialog for you." I suggest you use a DialogFragment instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onShow` to handle this like below:

```
val dialog = alertDialog.create()
dialog.setOnShowListener {
    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {
       var isValid = true

       if ( isEmpty(myedittext.text.toString()) ) {
           isValid = false
           Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }

       if ( isValid ) {
           Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "yeah!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           dialog.dismiss()
       }
    }
}

dialog.show()
```

Comment: Yeah ! It works ! Thks a lot ! I spent so much time on this issue, cool !

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if there's a way to bypass an alertdialog's buttons' functions. If there is, I've never found it. However, you could go with a much simpler solution. Just create your own "alert" view with an editText and buttons. Set the view to view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) or (View.GONE), and any of its children views will be invisible or gone as well. I generally, when this is necessary, do this with a semi-transparent black background behind the view as the parent; and set that view's visibility back and forth. Then, you can customize the functionality of the buttons and the rest of the view in any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the positive button to override the method onclick

you can use this code:

```
private fun showMyEditextDialog() {
    val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null)
    val myedittext = view.findViewById(R.id.myedittext) as EditText


    alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.title))
    alertDialog.setView(view)
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
    alertDialog.create()

    var dialog = alertDialog.create()
    dialog.show()
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {
        var isValid = true

        if ( isEmpty(myedittext.text.toString()) ) {
            isValid = false
            Toast.makeText(this, "empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        if ( isValid ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "yeah!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()        }

        if ( isValid ) {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah ! It works ! Thks a lot ! I spent so much time on this issue, cool !